# Highcharts. Series have same color after drilldown

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have some problems with highcharts. So, after i do drilldown series have same color, they extend it from column which was clicked, official highchart's  jsfidle perfectly demonstrate this behaviour (https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown)
In my config object i have array of colours, but it uses it only for initial view and after drilldown everything have the same color. I tried this option, but it didn't help:

```
chartOptions.plotOptions.column = {
                    colorByPoint: true
                };
```

Also had an idea to manually pick random color from array on each drilldown, but in this case i have problem with legend's item colours.
There must be some option to achieve it, but maybe i missing something.
Would be appreciate for any advice!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by defining `colorByPoint: true` property for each series. Like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
    drilldown: {
        series: [
            {
                colorByPoint: true,
                name: "Chrome",
                id: "Chrome",
                data: [
                   ...
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Firefox",
                id: "Firefox",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [
                   ...
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Internet Explorer",
                id: "Internet Explorer",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [
                   ...
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Safari",
                id: "Safari",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [
                   ...
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Edge",
                id: "Edge",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [
                   ...
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Opera",
                id: "Opera",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [
                   ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/30o1genk/

**UPD:** When you add series dynamically after a drilldown, your drilldown event handler should looks like this:

```
 events: {
    drilldown: function(e) {
      const point = e.point;

      const series = {
        colorByPoint: true, 
        data: [{name: "test", y: 10}, {name: "test2", y: 20}],
      };


      this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(point, series, false)  

      this.applyDrilldown();
    }
  }
```

Check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1fpdckn5/ for the dynamic case.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I tried your solution, but for some reason it doesnt work for my case, only difference is that i dynamically create series for drilldown and it still have same color. I updated jsfilde, please take a look.
https://jsfiddle.net/jnf842zd/

Comment: Your drilldown event handler was incorrect. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hey!) thanks for solution. It  indeed works, but in my case creates one small problem, i need to show legend and with this solution i will see only one item in it - "Series 1", instead of two, that are needed - "test", "test". So, will continue search for solution. But, again, thanks for help!)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a wanted color for each drilldown series.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1vbyp53w/

```
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
        name: "Chrome",
        id: "Chrome",
        color: 'orange',
        data: [
          ...
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Firefox",
        color: 'red',
        id: "Firefox",
        data: [
           ...
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Internet Explorer",
        id: "Internet Explorer",
        color: 'blue',
        data: [
           ...
        ]
      },

    ]
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.series